# How to write/flush the Rails log when the process dies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The Rails logger has the auto_flushing method. It delays writing to the log until the number of entries is the same as whatever this has been set to. This has been around since Rails 2, and is meant to speed things up by stopping constant writes to disk under load.

This is fine most of the time, but we have short running jobs that never hang around long enough to get past the flush - any errors disappear.

Is there any way to guarantee that the log is flushed when the process dies?

*EDIT*

In the end I did this (but it's very verbose)

```
af = Rails.logger.auto_flushing
Rails.logger.auto_flushing = true
Rails.logger.error "my message"
Rails.logger.auto_flushing = af
```

This forces the message out but puts auto flushing back afterwards

For the really complete solution put this in an initializer:

```
class << Rails.logger
  def flush_error( message )
    Rails.logger.error message
    Rails.logger.flush
  end
end
```

Then just use the method as and when ...

Comment: I'd be wary of causing a flush to happen on every logger call, it'll kill performance (but that may be ok in your case if you're not logging a whole log)

Comment: The *point* of this method is to only call flush when you want it, as in you might be chasing down a production problem that isn't arriving in the log before the process terminates - say in a resque task

Comment: OOC - have you actually experienced this kind of problem? When it happens - does the process throw an exception or just totally fail silently?

Comment: Fails silently - and even if it *did* throw an exception you wouldn't see it because it won't be flushed.

Comment: All of these answers are now invalid. Anyone knows how it works in Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4?

Answer (score 5):

If, for some reason, rails does not run the `at_exit` hook (flying monkeys absconding with your sanity), and you really *really* want those log entries, do as some people said and run this after the important logging statements:

```
Rails.logger.flush
```

or

```
logger.flush
```

Voila.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you set that to "1" and it will flush after every message?

```
config.logger.auto_flushing = 1
```

[**EDIT**: as madlep points out in a comment above - this is going to be a total resource hog and is likely not the best way of logging in general. But if you're bug-hunting - it's a way of finding it. That and switching your log to "debug level"]

You can also switch it off with:

```
config.logger.auto_flushing = false
```

But that just means you have to manually flush...

alternatively, you can specifically flush the log at the end of each of your scripts with:

```
Rails.logger.flush
```

Comment: This doesn't help - because I'm trying to leave the default behaviour in place, but make sure it flushes if the process terminates.

Comment: If the process terminates - then there is nothing left to flush the log. because it's dead... that's the point.

So the only alternative is to flush regularly so that everything *up to* the point where the process falls over... has made it to the log.

Comment: You're right - I was thinking in terms of the ever unreliable finalize method in Java, but unicorns/mongrels etc. just die

Comment: Yeah. Sadly that's the case for most processes (as opposed to threads, which I think is what Java uses with the finalize stuff). There is, in fact a "finalize" kind of equivalent called "ensure" - but it won't help at all if the process terminates suddenly. It simply ensures that stuff is done if an exception is raised within the block.

Comment: Can the downvoter at least explain why they downvoted? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: I wanted to put it back to 0 and it won't let me :( I meant to upvote the top one, sorry.

Comment: You should be able to click back on the down and it'll undo the down. You have enough reputation (just checked), so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
Signal.trap("EXIT") { Rails.logger.flush }
```

When you're initialising logging to register a signal handler with the process. When it dies, it'll execute whatever is in the block before terminating

See [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001428) for more info

(note - totally untested code with rails logger, but works in the general case of just *doing something* when the process dies.

Comment: This is definitely good to add to the code - but will only trap a voluntary exit... not when the process just dies (eg due to a SEGV or similar). Just sayin'. :)

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 3.1 this is no longer necessary: The code in Railties application/bootstrap.rb now includes at at_exit to flush the log.

Enjoy.